# GWT-voices with AppEngine datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, audio, google-cloud-datastore, clientbundle

I'm developing an app that plays lots of small mp3 files.
The mp3's are deployed to  App Engine as part of the Java project,
& played with GWT-voices via SoundController.createSound() which takes a URL.

2 problems:

1. Is there a limit on the amount of media I can deploy in this way? I'm intending to use 100's of small mp3's per app.
2. I need to edit the MP3 pool without having to redeploy the entire program & media. 
   I should really be using datastore in some form? How would that work? GWT-voices requires URLs, but from what I can see datastore doesn't deal with URLs?

Also, is there any (non-text) equivalent to ExternalTextResources (in a ClientBundle), 
to enable client-bundling of sound files with external caching?

Thanks for any ideas on this.